# Setting two different text files as seperate string arrays and finding matches from the two arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

So basically i'm trying to take two text files (one with many jumbled words and one with many dictionary words.) I am supposed to take these two text files and convert them to two seperate arrays.

Following that, I need to compare jumbled strings from the first array and match the dictionary word in the second array up to it's jumbled counterpart. (ex. aannab(in the first array) to banana(in the second array))

I know how to set one array from a string, however I don't know how to do two from two seperate text files.

Comment: Folks ,let's not discourage someone who is new to world of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HashMap` for matching. Where first text file data will be the key of `Map` and second text file data will be value. Then, by using key, you will get matching value.

Answer (score 0):

you can read each file into an array like this:

```
String[] readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
  List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
  try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       stringList.add(line);
    }
  } finally {
    br.close();
  }
    return stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]);
}
```

Next, try to do the matching:

```
String[] jumbles = readFile("jumbles.txt");
String[] dict = readfile("dict.txt);
for (String jumble : jumbles) {
   for (String word : dict) {
      // can only be a match if the same length
      if (jumble.length() == word.length()) {
         //next loop through each letter of jumble and see if it
         //appears in word.
      }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to set one array from a string, however I don't know how to do two from two seperate text files

I would encourage you to divide your problems don't knows and knows.
Search don't knows over internet you will get lot of ways to do it.
Then search for what you know,to explore whether it can be done in a better way.

To help you here,

Your Don't knows:

- Reading file in Java.
- Processing the content of read file.

Your known part :

- String to array representation ( Search whether there are better ways in your use case)

Combine both :-)

Comment: That was my fault, I meant that I do know how to set one array from a text file of strings, I don't know how to set two seperate arrays (one for each text file) although I think the biggest issue is how to get one word from a jumbled bunch of letters, although I do appreciate the help :)

Comment: logically if there are words in a text file then u should mark a word when u read a whitespace or a period(.) symbol...thats the logic to make out words that i used to use..hope it helps